# google closure geolocation api

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure-library

Is there a geolocation API part of google closure (ultimately for use in ClojureScript) ?

I've been looking for it, but all I can find is something that looks like an [old shim](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/externs/w3c_geolocation.js?r=7e3ff71630c12fd69bb63e3809f0a2b02e5d283b).

If there is none, is it because Google doesn't use that feature of web browsers (they find our location using other means), or because the browser API doesn't require that (already unified), and what would be the best alternative in ClojureScript ?

Comment: Nothing is in Closure for this right now. Generally, Closure only wraps these native APIs when there are cross-browser compatibility issues, is potential for a polyfill, or potential for improvement. I'm not personally too familiar with these APIs, but my guess is it's not in Closure because it's pretty standardized across the browsers that implement it. Is there something specific you're concerned about?

Comment: @joeltine that makes sense. I am concerned because (1) http://caniuse.com/#feat=geolocation -> look at known issues, and (2) because of the link I provided to an interface without implementation (why ?).

Comment: The "shim" link you provided is what's called an externs file. It's used in conjunction with the Closure Compiler to avoid renaming certain properties. See [this resource](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?hl=en) for more info.

Comment: On a side note, you should definitely avoid the Google code repository for Closure, it's obsolete. Use the GitHub version: https://github.com/google/closure-library/.

Comment: @joeltine thanks that makes sense now. I did not find it on github though.

Comment: @joeltine If you want to put that as an answer I would accept it by the way.

Comment: Answered added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is in Closure for this right now. Generally, Closure only wraps these native APIs when there are cross-browser compatibility issues, is potential for a polyfill, or potential for improvement. I'm not personally too familiar with these APIs, but my guess is it's not in Closure because it's pretty standardized across the browsers that implement it.

The "shim" link you provided is what's called an externs file. It's used in conjunction with the Closure Compiler to avoid renaming certain properties. See [this resource](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?hl=en) for more info.